# validation rule on when case status is closed then not possible to re-open

Tags: administration, validation-rule

my requirement is :
When case status is Approved or Rejected , then not possible to re-open the case and show alert like "Approved / Rejected cases not possible to open...."
How can we acheive through Validation rule ?
I tried below code but not works:

```
AND(
    TEXT( Status ) = "Approved",
    OR(
        TEXT(Status ) = "Rejected")
    )
```

pls correct or give any suggestions...Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This site isn't a free coding service, but rather one focused on helping people become better admins/developers by overcoming specific problems. If you've tried to write a validation rule to achieve this, you should [edit] your question to include what you've tried so far. If you're getting an error message, providing the full text of the error (don't paraphrase it!) is helpful. If you're new to Salesforce, or just a feature (like validation rules), then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is where you should start your learning journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a validation rule like below:

```
OR(
   TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) = 'Approved',
   TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) = 'Rejected'
)
```

Then just add your "Error Message" as: "Approved / Rejected cases not possible to open"

I would change the "Error Location" to Field and select "Status".

Keep in mind that this VR would apply to EVERY user, including Admins. If you would like to eliminate Admins or any Profile, that would need to be included in the VR as well. Let me know if that's the case.

Comment: Thank you Rodrigo....Appreciated

Comment: @Sekhar, if that solved your question, please make sure you accept the answer as correct, as it may help other users as well. Thanks.